# What role does MachineKey play in ASP.NET identity database tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, owin

I am working out a plan to move several ASP.NET 4.6.1 applications that use ASP.NET identity + SQL Server to a new database and set of web servers.  Currently, I have the following tables that were auto-created in SQL Server:

```
AspNetRoles
AspNetUserClaims
AspNetUserLogins
AspNetUserRoles
AspNetUsers
```

Currently all of these tables are empty, except AspNetUsers.  I am using OWIN + Google SSO/OAuth.

I want to move this ASP.NET application to a new server.  However, I just realized that I did not specify the machineKey in my web.config file.  I am worried that some of the data in these ASP.NET tables might become irrecoverable post-move.  **Is that an issue?**

For example, does the PasswordHash or SecurityStamp fields in AspNetUsers table use some locally-generated key that will not be set on the new web server, and thus cause all manner of authentication errors for my users?

Any help / guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any dependency to *machineKey* or anything else. You can move this tables anywhere you want.

Comment: That's great - so if I move the web server to be a different machine, different CPU, OS instance, ethernet MAC address, etc. - it will still be able to work as expected?